# Double integral limits

Tags: calculus, integration, bounds-of-integration

Evaluate the integral:  $\iint_D xydA$ where D is union of the two regions

[image]

The integral is given as :

$\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}xydydx+\int\limits_{-\sqrt3}^0 \int\limits^{\sqrt{1+y^2}}_{-y\sqrt3-1}xy\, dx\,dy $

But what I don't understand is in the first integral , $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1$ and this should imply $y$ varies from $0$ to $1$

Similarly in the second integral, $y$ varies from $0$ to $-\sqrt{3}$ implies $x$ varies from $-1$ to $2$

Yet they are not put as limits in the integration? Why is it so?

Comment: To find the limits in the inner integral, you need to fix a possible value of the exterior variable, in your case $x$. For each value of $x$, $y$ takes different values inside your region. Just look at vertical lines inside your region and you will see that $y$ varies within different ranges depending on the line you choose.

Comment: But when we fix x, then shouldn't it automatically fix y?

Comment: Not really. When you fix $x$, you are fixing a horizontal line. That line crosses your region. There is an "entry point" with some $y$-value, and an "exit point" with a different value of $y$. Those entry and exit values are the limits in the $y$ integral.

Comment: Can you define what you meant by entry and exit point? Is that the value of y at two fixed x points.

Comment: How to see exit and entry point in first integral?

Comment: Draw a vertical line $x=const$ with $const\in[-1,1]$. If you move up along the line, you first meet your region on the line joining $(-1,0)$ and $(2,-\sqrt{3})$, and you leave the region at a point on the semicircle $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Your lower limit for $y$ in the first integral is wrong. It is not zero, but the value of $y$ on the straight line, that you can easily find. The upper limit is OK.

Comment: The lower limit is $y=(-\sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{3})/3$

Comment: Got it. I understand how to take limits now